# Auto Startup Feature of Spring Cloud Function Not Working in Spring Native(in application.yml)

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, graalvm-native-image, spring-cloud-function, spring-native

---

I reviewed the problem and then opened a pull request to spring cloud stream.

So this problem is solved.

Pull Request Link : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/pull/2791

---

I can consume and produce data from kafka with **Spring Cloud Function**. Also, for consumers, I do not allow data to be consumed automatically when the service is starting(**auto-startup=false**). While the project is starting(Smart-Lifecycle), I want the data to be consumed after the initialization process of the data in the database is finished. My project works exactly as I described.

However, when I **build a native docker image with spring native**, various problems arise. Again, I can consume and produce data. **However, the auto-startup false feature doesn't work**. The auto-startup feature I wrote in **application.yml** does not work and does not throw an error. Although I do not start the relevant consumer in my code(programmaticaly), the service starts to consume data as soon as it stands up.

**Additional Info : If I run it without a native image, there is no problem. This problem occurs when I build native docker image and run it.**

**In addition, when I programmatically give false to auto-startup, this feature starts working. But I want to make it executable from application.yml. What should I do?**

My Project Github Link: [graalvm-spring-cloud-auto-startup](https://github.com/omercelikceng/graalvm-spring-cloud-auto-startup)

**Spring Boot Starter Parent Version : 3.1.2**

**Spring Cloud Version : 2022.0.4**

**GraalVM Version: 17**

My Code:

```
@Service("listenPersonData")
public class PersonListener implements Consumer<Person> {

    @Override
    public void accept(Person person) {
        System.out.println("Person Received : " + person.getName());
    }
}

@Service("personInitializer")
public class PersonInitializer implements SmartLifecycle {

    @Autowired
    private BindingsLifecycleController lifecycleController;

    @Override
    public void start() {
//        lifecycleController.changeState("listenPersonData-in-0", STOPPED);
//        Some Database Operation
        lifecycleController.changeState("listenPersonData-in-0", STARTED);
    }
}
```

Application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          replication-factor: 2
      bindings:
        listenPersonData-in-0:
          destination: deneme-person-topic-2
          binder: kafka1
          group: omer-celik-2243
          consumer:
            auto-startup: false
      function:
        definition: listenPersonData;
      binders:
        kafka1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:19092
                      autoCreateTopics: true
```

reflect-config.json

```
[
  {
    "condition": {
      "typeReachable": "org.springframework.kafka.security.jaas.KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer"
    },
    "name": "sun.security.provider.ConfigFile",
    "allPublicConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle",
    "allDeclaredFields": true
  },
  {
    "name": "org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle",
    "allDeclaredFields": true
  }
]
```

***Docker Image:
spring-boot:build-image -P native***

If I open the comment line code, the consumer is stopped. However, I want to stop it using application.yml. But my auto startup : false config in application.yml is not working.